# Exporting HTML to PDF and send the generated PDF via email in DJANGO

Tags: django, reportlab

I am using Django 1.10.3 and Reportlab to export html to pdf now I want to email the same generated pdf.I was able to generate the pdf but unable to email it. Please help me achieve it.

Here is my view:

```
def write_pdf_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="mypdf.pdf"'

    buff = StringIO()

    menu_pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(buff, rightMargin=72,
                                 leftMargin=72, topMargin=50, bottomMargin=18)

    elements = []
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='centered',fontName='Italic', alignment=TA_CENTER))
    elements.append(Paragraph('A good thing about WeasyPrint is that you can convert a HTML document to a PDF. So you can create a regular Django template, print and format all the contents and then pass it to the WeasyPrint library to do the job of creating the pdf.', style=styles["Normal"]))

    menu_pdf.build(elements)
    response.write(buff.getvalue())
    buff.close()
```

> Update:

```
subject = 'Welcome to Project Management Portal.'
message = 'Thank you for being part of us. \n We are glad to have you. \n Regards \n Team Project Management'

from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
to_list = [request.user.email, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]

message = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email, to_list)
pdf = open('mypdf.pdf', 'rb')
message.attach('mypdf-2.pdf', pdf, 'application/pdf')
message.send()
```

> Error:
>
> Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pdf_template/

Django Version: 1.10.3
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'Project',
 'UserManagement',
 'social.apps.django_app.default']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "E:\New folder\Aditya\ProjectManagement\Project\views.py" in pdf_view
  267.             message.send()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py" in send
  342.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in send_messages
  107.                 sent = self._send(message)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in _send
  121.         message = email_message.message()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py" in message
  306.         msg = self._create_message(msg)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py" in _create_message
  394.         return self._create_attachments(msg)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py" in _create_attachments
  407.                     msg.attach(self._create_attachment(*attachment))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py" in _create_attachment
  449.         attachment = self._create_mime_attachment(content, mimetype)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py" in _create_mime_attachment
  437.             Encoders.encode_base64(attachment)

File "C:\Python27\lib\email\encoders.py" in encode_base64
  45.     encdata = _bencode(orig)

File "C:\Python27\lib\email\encoders.py" in _bencode
  31.     hasnewline = (s[-1] == '\n')

Exception Type: TypeError at /pdf_template/
Exception Value: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: So far I been using 
http://pdfcrowd.com/forums/read.php?3,2153
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/

Comment: use wkhtmltopdf https://learnbatta.com/blog/django-html-to-pdf-using-pdfkit-and-wkhtmltopdf-5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try This:

```
def pdf_view(request):
fs = FileSystemStorage()
filename = 'mypdf.pdf'
if fs.exists(filename):
    with fs.open(filename) as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="mypdf.pdf"'

        subject = 'Welcome to Project Management Portal.'
        message = 'Thank you for being part of us. \n We are glad to have you. \n Regards \n Team Project Management'
        # message.attach = 'filename="mypdf.pdf", content_disposition="inline", data=open("mypdf.pdf", "rb")'
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_list = [request.user.email, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
        # send_mail(subject, message, message.attach, from_email, to_list)

        message = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email, to_list)
        # pdf = open('media/mypdf.pdf', 'rb')
        message.attach_file('media/mypdf.pdf')
        message.send()

        return response
else:
    return HttpResponseNotFound('The requested pdf was not found in our server.')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to just use `send_email` directly, and what you should be doing is building an `EmailMessage` object, and then attaching the file, and sending that. For example:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
message = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_email, to_list)
pdf = open('mypdf.pdf', 'rb')
message.attach('mypdf.pdf', pdf, 'application/pdf')
message.send()
```

Of course, if the PDF is on the filesystem, you might as well just use `attach_file()` instead of `attach()`. More info on that in [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/#s-emailmessage-objects) of the docs.

Comment: I used your code but i'don't know from where you are getting 'mypdf.pdf' file as I want to use the pdf file I generated with Reportlab.Can you please tell me how can I attach that file with mail.I have updated the code above I am trying now so please check my code as well.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you'd generated it on the filesystem, based on what you were trying. Instead of using the `pdf` variable as I showed in my code, you could use your `buf`, which is a file object anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution all I had to do was to save the pdf in the project and I did it by using SimpleDocTemplate and then attached the same file by giving its location.
Here is what I did:

> view:

```
def write_pdf_view(request):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("media/mypdf.pdf", rightMargin=72, leftMargin=72, topMargin=-70)
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    Story = [Spacer(1, 2 * inch)]
    style = styles["Normal"]
    paratext = ("A good thing about WeasyPrint is that you can convert a HTML document to a PDF. So you can create a regular Django template, print and format all the contents and then pass it to the WeasyPrint library to do the job of creating the pdf.")
    p = Paragraph(paratext, style)
    Story.append(p)
    Story.append(Spacer(1, 0.2 * inch))
    doc.build(Story)    
    subject = 'Welcome to Project Management Portal.'
    message = 'Thank you for being part of us. \n We are glad to have you. \n Regards \n Team Project Management'
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    to_list = [request.user.email, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
    message = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email, to_list)
    message.attach_file('media/mypdf.pdf')
    message.send()    
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'The PDF is sent Successfully !!')
    return redirect('home')
```